# Promedios Moviles en Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

me gustaría saber si existe en Python una función específica para calcular promedios móviles. En MATLAB hay una que se llama "tsmovavg" que tiene un algoritmo llamado "Financial Time Series". Existirá el mismo algoritmo en Python?

Comment: [`pandas.rolling_mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.rolling_mean.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
N = 3
cumsum, moving_averages = [0], []

for i, x in enumerate(list, 1):
    cumsum.append(cumsum[i-1] + x)
    if i>=N:
        moving_ave = (cumsum[i] - cumsum[i-N])/N
        #Puedes hacer cosas con el promedio movil aquí
        moving_averages.append(moving_ave)
```